# When using a redeemed code through Volume Purchase, who owns the copy of a B2B app, ultimately?

Tags: ios-appstore, mobile-device-management, enterprise

I've been looking into various distribution options for enterprise-y iOS apps and one question I can't figure out remains: if my client does a volume purchase and chooses to use redeem codes to hand out to the end users, is it **still** the case that ownership of the app ends up at the end user's Apple ID? Are there any mechanisms (short of MDM) that allow the purchasing client to retain ownership?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the relevant excerpt of the iTunes Store Terms and Conditions:

https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/volume/us/terms.html#VOLUME

> CONTENT CODES
>
> [...] YOU UNDERSTAND AND AGREE THAT THE OWNER OF THE
>   REDEEMING ITUNES ACCOUNT WILL BECOME (i) FOR AN APP STORE PRODUCT, THE
>   LICENSEE OF THAT COPY OF THE PRODUCT; AND (ii) FOR AN IBOOKS STORE
>   PRODUCT, THE OWNER OF THAT COPY OF THE PRODUCT, AND SHALL BE ENTITLED
>   TO ALL ASSOCIATED RIGHTS. SUCH LICENSES OR PRODUCTS ARE
>   NON-TRANSFERABLE.

for short: only managed distribution retains ownership!